# Python Typecasting

Tags: python, type-conversion, raw-input

I have taken a number as a raw_input and stored it in a variable port.
However, I have to use this number(stored as a string) as a parameter in an "if" statement. 
I cannot take the number as "input" as I require that number as a string later.
I tried typecasting the string to an int but it is not working.
How do I use the raw_input as a number?

```
port = raw_input("Enter the port no:")
temp = int(port)

if (temp >> 0 or temp << 323):
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you intending to using bit shift operators here? Are you just looking to check for greater than/less than?

Comment: You probably wanted to type > and <

Comment: conditional should have been of the form  `((temp > 0) and (temp < 323))`

Comment: The > was the problem. I am so used to coding in C++ that I overlooked the simple comparators.Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in your comparison in your `if` statment, change `temp >> 0`to `temp > 0`

Or, what you want is a `try / catch` or a  `try / except ValueError` like :

```
port = raw_input("Enter the port no:")
try:
  temp = int(port)
except ValueError:
  print("That's not an int! Please provide a valid port")

 if (0 < temp < 323):
```